# Convert a text file with no sapces to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

So, I have text file like this,

```
ZIP BLDGNO1 STREET1 STSUFX1 BLDGNO2 STSUFX2 CITY COUNTY STATUS1 BLOCK LOT
11201 131 AMITY ST BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A 291 45
11201 141 AMITY ST 86 AVE BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A 291 40
ZIP BLDGNO1 STREET1 STSUFX1 BLDGNO2 STSUFX2 CITY COUNTY STATUS1 BLOCK LOT
11201 372 BALTIC ST BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A 403 30
11201 375 BALTIC ST BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A 397 7505
```

I want to convert the text file to pandas dataframe so that I can export it to csv later. The output should look like this,

```
ZIP  BLDGNO1 STREET1 STSUFX1 BLDGNO2 STSUFX2 CITY COUNTY STATUS1             BLOCK   LOT
11201 131     AMITY    ST                  BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A   291     45  
11201 141     AMITY    ST     86      AVE  BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A   291     40
11201 372    BALTIC    ST                  BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A   403     30
11201 375    BALTIC    ST                  BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A   397     7505
```

I have tried this so far but it doesn't really break up the columns instead it just put everything in single column.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(path+"filename.txt",header=None,sep='\t')
df.head()
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure those gaps in between are tabs? looks a lot like spaces to me. In fact, I copied it and separate with spaces worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried with spaces as well. No difference still the same.

Comment: oh. Just saw the read part. do this ```pd.read_csv(path+'filename.txt', sep=' ')```

Comment: `11201 141 AMITY ST 86 AVE BROOKLYN 61 MULTIPLE DWELLING A 291 40` has to many columns.  Your data set is not properly formed. Each column must have the same form and without a consistent separator, it's not going to be easy.  You will have to read it in with the CSV library and fix your dataset first.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney this is how the text file is. Some of them have missing data for some of the columns.

Comment: Saw that you edited the data. As @TrentonMcKinney mentioned, you might need to import that using csv library and pre-process each line. Only hope is that you know some of those column's data types and patterns. Use that to decide where it belongs to.

Comment: @TharakaDevinda Tried your code. Now it has  spaces but still can't separate them based on columns.